# How to Correctly Bind Properties to Form Events?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am doing a tutorial from the HeadFirst C# Book. The form itself WAS working before but now it isnt, and I dont remember what I changed. I've gone over the text several times now and it appears to be a verbatim copy, yet it doesnt work. What am I doing wrong? I imagine the problem must be in the Form.cs file.

Here is the code for the class.

```
    class DinnerParty
    {
        public const int CostOfFoodPerPerson = 25;

        //declare DinnerParty automatic properties
        public int NumberOfPeople { get; set; }
        public bool HealthyOption { get; set; }
        public bool FancyDecorations { get; set; }

        // Setup Object Constructor with parameters masking the properties
        public DinnerParty(int numberOfPeople, bool healthyOption, bool fancyDecorations)
        {
            //Set Property Values to parameter values
            NumberOfPeople = numberOfPeople;
            HealthyOption = healthyOption;
            FancyDecorations = fancyDecorations;


        }

        //  Use private methods to access public properties bound to the form.

        private decimal CalculateCostOfBeveragesPerPerson()
        {
            decimal costOfBeveragesPerPerson;
            if (HealthyOption)
            {
                costOfBeveragesPerPerson = 5.00M;
            }
            else
            {
                costOfBeveragesPerPerson = 20.00M;
            }
            return costOfBeveragesPerPerson;
        }


        protected decimal CalculateCostOfDecorations()
        {
            decimal costOfDecorations;
            if (FancyDecorations)
            {
                costOfDecorations = (NumberOfPeople * 15.00M) + 50M;
            }
            else
            {
                costOfDecorations = (NumberOfPeople * 7.50M) + 30M;
            }
            return costOfDecorations;
        }

        //declare read only Cost property to be bound to costLabel control
        public decimal Cost
        {
            get
            {
                decimal totalCost = CalculateCostOfDecorations();
                totalCost += ((CalculateCostOfBeveragesPerPerson() + CostOfFoodPerPerson) * NumberOfPeople);
                if (HealthyOption)
                {
                    totalCost *= .95M;
                }
                return totalCost;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the code for the form.

```
namespace DinnerParty
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DinnerParty dinnerParty;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //Initialize DinnerParty object. Initialize DinnerParty party with      default form values.
            dinnerParty = new DinnerParty((int) numericUpDown1.Value, healthyBox.Checked , fancyBox.Checked);
            DisplayDinnerPartyCost();
        }

        // Bind form controls to DinnerParty Properties
        private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           dinnerParty.NumberOfPeople = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;
            DisplayDinnerPartyCost();
        }

        private void fancyBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dinnerParty.FancyDecorations = fancyBox.Checked;
            DisplayDinnerPartyCost();

        } 

        private void healthyBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dinnerParty.HealthyOption = healthyBox.Checked;
            DisplayDinnerPartyCost();
        }

        private void DisplayDinnerPartyCost()
        {
            decimal Cost = dinnerParty.Cost;
            costLabel.Text = Cost.ToString("c");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This question doesn't follow the guidelines for this site. What specifically is not working? [FAQ]

Comment: I updated the question. Is that more clear? Sorry.

Comment: If you are copying code, make sure you wire the event handlers again in the designer, or manually, `healthyBox.CheckedChanged += healthyBox_CheckedChanged;`

Comment: Thank you!!! This worked. I knew it had to be something simple! Thank you so much! I would never have found this lol.

Answer (score 0):

The below line in your code might be wrong. I am not seeing any class DinnerParty2. Change it as DinnerParty

```
 dinnerParty = new DinnerParty2((int) numericUpDown1.Value,   healthyBox.Checked , fancyBox.Checked);
```

Comment: Sorry, I thought I changed them all back. I was trying to figure it out so I just copied the same file into a new form and named it DinnerParty2. I just changed it so it mirrors the original.

It compiles correctly with no errors.

Comment: Thanks. If any of the solution provided my stack overflow members helps you please  accept the solution. You can do that by clicking on the tick mark nearer to the answer.

Comment: The problem wasn't a compilation error, I never had problems getting it to compile. The solution to the problem was actually posted above by LarsTech, but he didnt submit it as an "answer" so I cant mark him correct. Maybe you can, I dont know.I appreciate your contribution though.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, if you are copying code, then make sure you wire the event handlers again in the designer, or manually:

```
healthyBox.CheckedChanged += healthyBox_CheckedChanged;
```

because when you copy and paste controls, the event handlers are not included.